# Increase the limit of Picklist in Vtiger 6.4

Tags: vtiger

I am using vtiger 6.4 and I want to add many options in picklist field but currently its not possible to add more than 20. Can somebody help me to increase this limit to 100?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: write a script where entries will directly add into database table of picklist.

Comment: Thanks @sAcH anybody else with more profound explanation/elaboration with technical insights.